# Transform dataset to regression problem by sorting?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, dataset, active-learning

I have a raw unlabeled dataset, and I want to design a model to perform a regression. In my dataset, it does not make sense to give each observation a value, but it does make sense to sort them. Can I implement an algorithm to create values for each observation by sorting them?

I thought about this:

1. Select N random observations and sort them
2. Give each observation a new score, equal to its position
3. Calculate the score of an observation as the average position across all times the observation was picked
4. return to step 1

Does it make sense? Is there any machine learning branch that studies this kind of scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a field for this called ordinal regression. Does each unique observation have it's own rank or can observations share a rank? IE. if you have 10 elements, are they labeled 1,2,3 ... 10? or could it be 1,1,1, 2,2,2,3,3,3,4? *can't post as comment due to karma*
What are these values supposed to represent? Why are you doing this analysis?

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Each observation could have its own rank or share a rank. It is an arbitrary decision. I guess it is simpler to suppose each one have its own rank

Comment: So are you trying to create a model to pit item A vs item B and decide which is higher ranked? Using the attributes to explain why item A or B is higher ranked?

Comment: Yes to the first question. No to the second: I don't need an explanation of why A>B.

Comment: Will you always be comparing just two elements at a time?

Comment: No, I thought about comparing in batches of 10 elements (N=10).

Comment: Why not just sort the whole data set? Can you post a few hundred rows of the data set or share a visualization of what you are hoping to do? To be frank, i'm a bit lost here.

Comment: I didn't thought about sorting the whole dataset to decrease the cost... Unfortunately I cannot share the data for confidentiality reasons

Comment: sorry I can't be of more help. But Ordinal regression is where I'd look first.